# How to stop timer if a Listbox is empty or items are less than 0 in winform applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a windows app.

- A button1 which gets the items in listBox1 from server at the start.
- A button2 which starts the timer1.
- A timer1 which removes items from listBox1 .
- A progressBar1 which shows the progress of this process.

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    jabber.Send("<iq type='get' to='" + textBox1.Text + "@conference.jabber.com' id='qip_1026'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item affiliation='outcast' /></query></iq>");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Interval = 4000;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        jabber.Send("<iq type='set' to='" + textBox7.Text + "@conference.jabber.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item jid='" + listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "' affiliation='none'/></query></iq>");
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
        label.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = False;
    }
}
```

The above code works well till there is one item left in listBox1.

The error is:

*System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled 
Message=InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 
Parameter name: index*

It raises an error when listBox1 reaches 0. I want to stop the timer when listbox1 is empty or gets no items or 0 items.

Comment: i know where to stop the timer.// if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0) then execute the code otherwise stop the timer.but that is not working

Comment: Not telling us what the error is, or which line causes it, doesn't help your audience understand the issue.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: What's with `timer3`? And for consistency (and the compiler's happiness) make that `timer1.Stop();`

Comment: We can only guess that you have some other code that is interfering with the listBox1.Items collection between the time you check that the Items.Count > 0 and when you try to remove the item.

Comment: I have edited the code .now its fully clear.If not let me tell you when the timer1 starts it starts removing or deleting items from listBox1.It works well Till 1 item in listBox1.After that it shows error as there is nothing to remove in listBox1.

Comment: I hope now the question is clear.

Comment: The problem is not that the question is unclear. It is that you don't tells us enough. Which line brings up the error??? One of lines in the Tick event? Hard to believe! Did you debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            jabber.Send("<iq type='set' to='" + textBox7.Text + "@conference.jabber.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item jid='" + listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "' affiliation='none'/></query></iq>");
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
            label.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = False;
        }
    }
```

So what is happening is that you are using count to check >0 then calling jabber to do the work, It the call becomes slow- you will see multiple timers getting fired back. So a big queue will be collected there. You need to modify the code a bit here using lock to hold the list and allow jabber to do its work:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (listBox1)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                jabber.Send("<iq type='set' to='" + textBox7.Text +
                            "@conference.jabber.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item jid='" +
                            listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "' affiliation='none'/></query></iq>");
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                progressBar1.Value += 1;
                label.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = False;
            }
        }
    }
```

Lock will also ensure that the items are removed correctly.
To save the file as per comment below :

```
 public class ChatHistoryManager
{
    private readonly RichTextBox richTextBox;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    public ChatHistoryManager(RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        this.richTextBox = richTextBox;
        this.InitializeTimer();
    }

    public string Location { get; set; }
    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        this.timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        this.timer.Enabled = true;          
        this.timer.Interval = (int) TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveFile();
    }

    public void SaveFile()
    {
        //Save the file to the location
        this.richTextBox.SaveFile(this.Location,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Now we need to set in form like this:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChatHistoryManager chatHistoryManager = new ChatHistoryManager(this.richTextBox1);
        chatHistoryManager.Location = @"C:\Development\test.txt";
    }
```

Comment: One More Thing i wanna ask.

Comment: Hi, no prob, sure , let me know what and can look into it.

Comment: I was using above in a chat application.I have a richtextBox1 in my application which is used for live chat.how can i save the chat history after every single hour in text file.with proper formatting and location on hard drive.

Comment: The quickest way is to use Timer that can fire every 1 hour to save. So create a class like ChatHistoryManager that can take this Richtextbox in constructor and this class also has a timer that will fire every 1 hour. Now in the main form you just need to use this class to set the richtextbox and the class can then do its stuff. You can add more properties in this class like folder path, restore(), forcesave(), stop etc.. All the code will be in separate class incase you face any debugging issues.

Comment: Rich text box also has a  method: this.richTextBox.SaveFile(); which can save in proper format to a location

Comment: Have a look at my answer above - added the class there. Let me know and can enhance more if reqd. You can set the timer to anything you want. Main is location should be set with the richtextbox and then timer will just save the file. In the form you just need to do new ChatHistoryManager(RichTextbox..) and set its location. You may not need  this.timer.Start(); as well and it should fire fine - reduce the time to 1 min to try

Comment: Works fine- I tried the code and saving file after 1 second and it works fine. Have shown the code above to be used in form as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55645/discussion-between-dr-zeus-and-avneesh).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            int count = City.Items.Count - 1;
            for (int i = count; i > 0; i--){
                City.Items.RemoveAt(i);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
jabber.Send("<iq type="get" to="" + textBox1.Text + "@conference.jabber.com" id="qip_1026"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item affiliation="outcast" /></query></iq>");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
progressBar1.Value = 0;
// Set the timer interval to four seconds
timer1.Interval = 4000;
// Start the timer
timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
// Disable the timer while we are working in this procedure so
// it doesn't tick while we are working in this procedure
timer1.Enabled = False;
// Send only if there are items in the ListBox
if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    jabber.Send("<iq type="set" to="" + textBox7.Text + "@conference.jabber.com"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item jid="" + listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "" affiliation="none" /></query></iq>");
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    progressBar1.Value += 1;
    label.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
}
// Re-enable only if there are items left in the ListBox
if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
     timer1.Enabled = True;
}
 }
```